# While loop for number's between 10 to 100

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, integer

Trying to continue a while loop if false but I cannot figure it out I have this so far

```
int_a = input("Enter a interger from 10 and 100 :")
int_a = int(int_a)


# While greater than zero.
while int_a >=10:
    if int_a<=100:
       print ("The integer you entered is", int_a)
    break
```

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 1):

> Trying to continue a while loop if false

So while loop for numbers **not** between 10 and 100.

```
while True:
    int_a = input("Enter a interger from 10 and 100 :")
    int_a = int(int_a)

    if (10 <= int_a <= 100):
        # Correct number, break the while loop
        break

    # Wrong number
    print ("The integer you entered is wrong")
    # While loop restarts automatically here

# Here int_a is in the correct range
print ("The integer you entered is", int_a)
```

Comment: I understand that part but how do I restart the loop from the start if they dont enter a number within 10 and 100?

Comment: The loop restarts automatically as long as its condition (`int_a < 10 or int_a > 100`) is `True` so after the loop the number is between 10 and 100

Comment: so for example if I enter "7" the loop starts again but what if I want a error message before the user can input another number?